# Caches node of Cassandra jconsole is not expandable

Tags: caching, cassandra, jmx, jconsole

I have 1 node of Cassandra 1.1.2 installed on Linux, and I want to determine the size that every CF is occupying in the cache, and how many percents of every CF is in the cache (both for row cache and key cache)

When I connecting to this node via jconsole, and I'm expanding the org.apache.cassandra.db node in jconsole, the 'Caches' node is unexpandable, although according to:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/monitoring#monitoring-and-adjusting-cache-performance

It should be expandable.

In addition, the output of the nodetool also does not contain the properties
Key cache capacity, Key cache size and Key cache hit rate:

```
            Column Family: io2
            SSTable count: 4
            Space used (live): 566387478
            Space used (total): 566387478
            Number of Keys (estimate): 3858816
            Memtable Columns Count: 0
            Memtable Data Size: 0
            Memtable Switch Count: 0
            Read Count: 0
            Read Latency: NaN ms.
            Write Count: 0
            Write Latency: NaN ms.
            Pending Tasks: 0
            Bloom Filter False Postives: 0
            Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom Filter Space Used: 7238040
            Compacted row minimum size: 125
            Compacted row maximum size: 149
            Compacted row mean size: 149
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Caches node of Cassandra jconsole is not expandable in Cassandra  1.1.2,
because individual per cf caches were combined into a global cache in 1.1,
thus it is not possible to see these fields in 1.1.2

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/caching-in-cassandra-1-1